# Android application crashes if JSON don't return any data

Tags: android, json

I built an android application that reads the user location (latitude and longitude) and sends the result to an API to show nearby locations.
When the API is have trouble finding the user location or there are no nearby places found by the API, the application crashes.
Actually I'm using the following method, and I think the crash comes from there:

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            // check if the view already exists
            // if so, no need to inflate and findViewById again!
            if (convertView == null) {

                // Inflate the custom row layout from your XML.
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_book, null);

                // create a new "Holder" with subviews
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) getItem(position);
 // Grab the title and author from the JSON
            if (!jsonObject.isNull("placeName")) {
                String placeName = jsonObject.optString("placeName");

                // Send these Strings to the TextViews for display
                holder.titleTextView.setText(placeName);
            }

            return convertView;
        }
```

I'm looking for solution to show default message if there are no places around (no JSON data at all). Better than application crash!

I'm usually testing my app on my physical device, but when I did in the Android Studio run option:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:2968)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:3248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at pack.MainActivity.queryBooks(MainActivity.java:122)
            at pack.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:19)
            at pack.MainActivity$1.gotLocation(MainActivity.java:63)
            at pack.MyLocation$GetLastLocation.run(MyLocation.java:114)
            at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Edit:
I've found out that my API returns error 204 - No content when the query returns no results.
I thought that this information might help to solve the solution.

Edit 2:
Ok. The application crashed because the API returned error 204 - No content.
Luckily I have control over the API and I changed it to show empty json object and it didn't crash.

Comment: could you post your log cat please?

Comment: Couldn't you just send a error message has a JSON object ? Like `array('error' => 'No location founs')` ?

Comment: @user3641702 I edited my question with the log cat error.

Comment: @Scalpweb huh? I can't place it anywehere

Comment: Are you trying to access the UI component from your child thread?

Comment: @ShadowDroid I'm using ProgressDialog gpsDialog and show "checking your location.." message in the OnCreate, and dismissing it when it finds a location

Comment: @TheUnreal from which thread you are dismissing the dialog.

Comment: @ShadowDroid The same one, mainActivity.

Comment: what is line MainActivity.java:122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application crashed because the API returned error 204 - No content. 
The application tried to read JSOn data from "No Content" web url, and it crashed.
Luckily I have control over the API and I changed it to show empty json object and it didn't crash.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            // check if the view already exists
            // if so, no need to inflate and findViewById again!
            if (convertView == null) {

                // Inflate the custom row layout from your XML.
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_book, null);

                // create a new "Holder" with subviews
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) getItem(position);
 // Grab the title and author from the JSON
            if (!jsonObject.isNull("placeName")) {
                String placeName = jsonObject.optString("placeName");

                // Send these Strings to the TextViews for display
                holder.titleTextView.setText(placeName);
            }else if(jsonObject.isNull("placeName")){
Log.i("JsonObject", "Null");
}

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: Sometimes it worked (when it found a nearby places), when it's dont: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`